# How can I run the "tar" command in WindowsXP?

Tags: windows-xp, tar

I need to run the "tar" command (to decompress a file) within WindowsXP.
Do I need a i.e Linux emulator ?

Comment: How exactly is this programming related?  Just because someone wants to *run* a program, it doesn't therefore qualify as a programming question.

Comment: -1: Couldn't make google work, either.

Answer (score 10):

First hit when googling for [tar windows](http://www.google.ca/search?q=tar+windows) seems relevant.. [Tar for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gtar.htm)

Answer (score 8):

[GNU Tar is available](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gtar.htm) as a native Windows application. However, many archiving utilities available for Windows can handle the Tar format, including my personal favourite, the excellent [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/).

Answer (score 5):

No. You have quite a lot of options; here are two:

1. [Unix utilities for Windows](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/)
2. [7-ZIP](http://www.7-zip.org/)

Comment: Does 7-ZIP  produce pure tars or does it produce it's flavor of tar?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. It's included in [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).

But I think the easier way is to open tar archives with [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/), it comes with LGPLd library.

Answer (score 3):

Or download the Win32 version of tar here: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gtar.htm

Just click the section where it says "binaries".

Comment: Those are great. Gnuwin32 tools are unix to the spirit unlike those from cygwin. Cygwin tools are unix to the letter through aid of nasty kludges :(

Answer (score 2):

[WinZip](http://www.winzip.com/index.htm) can read tar files.

Answer (score 2):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils is a collection of binary Unix utilities that includes tar.

Answer (score 1):

If you need Linux "emulator", you can use Cygwin [link text](http://www.cygwin.com).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want **tar** then Ryan Graham's is the best solution. If you need some of the other UNIX tools but don't want the vast amount of bloat that Cygwin has unhappily become, see [Minmalist GNU for Windows](http://www.mingw.org/).

Comment: or http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils, a collection of Unix utilities compiled to native Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I've been impressed with [TugZip](http://www.tugzip.com/). It handles a bunch of compressed formats including tar and tgz (and it's free).